# Многопоточная компиляция с использованием MinGW-w64 g++

Tags: c++, g++, visual-studio-code, mingw-w64

возможно ли задействовать все ядра процессора, чтобы ускорить компиляцию программы? Работаю в Visual Code C++, Windows 10.

Comment: Чтобы ускорить компиляцию программы сначала следует определить, почему она занимает много времени. А то люди бросаются делать многопроцессную и даже распределенную компиляцию, а сборка все равно идет медленно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разрезайте программу на единицы трансляции (`cpp`-файлы), а потом запускайте компиляцию параллельно - если вы используете `make`

```
make -j [число потоков]
```

Учитывая, что компиляция состоит не сколько в нагрузке на процессор, сколько в нагрузке на диск, число потоков уместно задавать, умножив количество ядер на 3-4.

Хороших результатов можно добиться, разместив исходные тексты, файлы компилятора и выходную папку на ram-диске.

Программа `distcc` позволяет запускать компиляцию на распределенной сети машин.